# Running time of this algorithm?

Tags: algorithms

```
k ← 1
for i ← 1 to n do
    while k < 9i do
        k ← k + 1
        x ← x^2

 “← ” denotes the assignment statement. The scope of and nesting loops is indicated
by the indentation.
```

Why is the runtime of this algorithm only $\theta$(n)? I thought the second loop would iterate 9 * i times so it would be $\theta(n^2)$.

Comment: I would agree that the runtime is $\Theta(n^2)$.

Comment: @Math1000 : How many times do you think the inner loop runs?

Comment: @EricTowers Oh right, $k\leftarrow 1$ is outside the loop. Never mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that the inner loop always runs exactly $9$ times (... because $k$ is *not* reset to $1$ in the outer loop) except the first time, when it only runs $8$ times, since $k$ does not start at $0$.